# CSS Animation is only working in Edge

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a CSS animation that I do I not see a problem with. There are two parts to it, first the "fade" and then the "move". The part not working is the "move" animation. Surprisingly, the full animation works in Microsoft Edge but fails in every other browser i.e Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
#about {
visibility: hidden;
     -webkit-animation: fadein1 .5s, move1 .5s; 
       -moz-animation:  fadein1 .5s, move1 .5s;  
         -o-animation:  fadein1 .5s, move1 .5s;
}

#about.open {
visibility: visible;
      -webkit-animation: fadein .5s, move .5s; 
        -moz-animation:  fadein .5s, move .5s;  
          -o-animation:  fadein .5s, move .5s; 
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
    from {top: 50px;}
    to {top: 0px;}
}

@-o-keyframes move {
    from {top: 50px;}
    to {top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes move {
    from {top: 50px;}
    to {top: 0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    from {top: 50px;}
    to {top: 0px;}
}


@-moz-keyframes move1 {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 50px;}
}

@-o-keyframes move1 {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 50px;}
}

@keyframes move1 {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 50px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
    from {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 50px;}
}


@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}


@keyframes fadein1 {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein1 {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein1 {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein1 {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: @keyframes missing ! please check syntax..

Comment: I added the missing keyframes but it's still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animations `move` and `move1` doesn't have a `@keyframes`, with no prefix.

Edit:

Add `position:relative;` to your `#about`, and the moves should work. if you haven't specified a position (relative, absolute or fixed), the browser can't move it.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain further? I'm a bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: I added the keyframes but the same result still occurs. The fadein animation is working well but the move is not animating at all.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It looks like you are missing `position` for your #about.

Comment: Thanks! So that was the problem. It's weird how it works in Edge without the position.

Comment: @LordGoderick When no browser works with your code except Edge, it's not likely Edge is doing it correctly. Far more likely, Edge let it slide rather than sticking to the specification. Never a good thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.